# Why perpendicular component of Electric field is discontinuous across the boundary and parallel components continuous?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, boundary-conditions

I was going through Griffith's electrodynamics boundary conditions and have a problem understanding the discontinuity of $E_\perp$ components.

While deriving the electric field for an infinite sheet of charge he added the area of pillbox 2 times under Gauss's law

$$EA+EA= \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$$

But while explaining boundary conditions he added the area only once and as an infinite sheet of charge has an electric field normal to the surface which equals:

E=sigma/2 epsilon_0 n^ and has no tangential components hence there should not be any parallel components while calculating boundary conditions ,and the tangential components should have zero electric field.

And as on the surface both electric fields are equal and oppositely directed they should have $E=0$ at surface for perpendicular components.

Comment: Why are you bringing up the tangential electric field when asking about the perpendicular component? Once you cross a plane with charge, the electric field must change. What do you mean with "here it looks otherwise "? Where is "here"? It's not clear to me what you don't understand. This is probably because, when you don't understand something, it can be hard to explain what it is you don't understand... I urge you to try to clarify your question - what is the concept you are struggling with. When you can explain that you may be halfway to finding the answer yourself...

Comment: Welcome to Physics StackExchange!  I must confess I find your question rather confusing.  Can you clarify what you mean in your paragraph that starts, "But here it looks otherwise..."?

Comment: Edited my question..hopefully it makes some sense now...sorry fr that...by otherwise I meant as the electric field at the surface should be Eabove-Ebelow= 0 as both the fields above and below are equal and oppositely directed